# Iterating multiple children nodes using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having trouble iterating this structure. I know there are a few approaches using Jackson and I'm hoping someone could provide a quick and manageable solution.

The JSON structure is consistent throughout and every child will have a "children" field regardless of its size.

I would like to output **field1, field 2, and field3** for each node. Hierarchy of the nodes is irrelevant.

```
{
    "field1": "example data",
    "field2": "example data2",
    "field3": "example data3",
    "children": [{
        "field1": "example data",
        "field2": "example data2",
        "field3": "example data3",
        "children": [{
                "field1": "example data",
                "field2": "example data2",
                "field3": "example data3",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "field1": "example data",
                "field2": "example data2",
                "field3": "example data3",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "field1": "example data",
        "field2": "example data2",
        "field3": "example data3",
        "children": [{
            "field1": "example data",
            "field2": "example data2",
            "field3": "example data3",
            "children": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Hierarchy is irrelevant here. A simple output of the 3 values within the structure is all that I would need. I am updating OP to reflect those requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The streaming API provides a simple solution:

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(json);

while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    String name = parser.getCurrentName();
    if ("field1".equals(name)) {
        parser.nextToken();                 // Advance to the field value
        String value = parser.getText();    // Get the field value as a string
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
parser.close();
```

Usually the streaming API requires a lot more work to use, but in this case (because hierarchy isn't important) it seems appropriate.

Comment: What are the benefits of using the streaming API? Is it more efficient in terms of memory and CPU?

Comment: The benefit of streaming is the same benefit that SAX parsing of XML provides over DOM parsing.  You don't incur the overhead of representing the date as a bunch of unused objects in memory.  It can be faster if you process only to the desired point then terminate the parsing loop.